# System.Numerics.BigInteger not found when using different versions of MsBuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, rake, orchardcms, albacore

I'm having a problem on my CI machine (Jenkins) in the sense that a project (based on OrchardCMS but I don't think it is related), fails to build based on what msbuild executable is run.

Namely, I use rake with albacore to run the build and it automatially picks up msbuild from here:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

In this case one of the projects fail with a

```
error CS0012: The type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' is defined 
              in an assembly that is not referenced. [...]
```

If I instead use the msbuild coming from here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin`

Everything seems to work ok. My question is if this is normal or if there is any special differences between the two. Do they carry across different libraries from the GAC maybe?

Any help in understanding is appreciated. I would like to keep using rake with albacore and not switch build method for this project only.

Answer (score 0):

local or GAC but you probably would need to reference System.Numerics.dll in project reference whichever includes code file with specific [BigInteger type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have .NET Framework 4.6.1 but I suppose .NET Framework 4.0 and above should have dll located as - 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Numerics.dll

Hope this helps